# JS Funcional como iniciar

Tags: javascript

Ola, alguem poderia me dar uma força, como melhorar isso para js funcional

```
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
  var dtAlterar = newArr[1].dtAlterar;
  if(newArr[i].dtAlterar != dtAlterar){
    var igual = 'diferente'
    break;
  }else{
    var igual = 'igual'
  }
}
```

Comment: O que queres fazer? transformar isso numa função? podes dar um exemplo da aplicação que queres fazer?

Comment: Não sei se é o caso de inserir essa dica no comentário :p, mas tem uma API para várias linguagens (incluindo js) que estou estudando que é voltado para programação funcional. [ReactiveX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs)

Comment: Qual é o objetivo deste código? Ele compara a propriedade `dtAlterar` de todos os elementos do array com o segundo elemento e não fazer nada com esse resultado?
Se tu explicar melhor vai ser mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: Entao, preciso comparar itens do array, se forem iguais retorna igual, caso valor for deferente esta retornando diferente

Comment: Achei Uma Linda solucao para nossso problemas rsrs https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi você quer checar se uma propriedade de todos os itens do array são iguais e retornar o resultado, veja se isso te atende:

```js
function compareArrayValues(arr, field, callback) {
  var response = 'Igual';
  
  for(x in arr) {
    if(arr[x][field] != arr[0][field]) {
      response = 'Diferente';
      break;
    }
  }
  
  callback(response);
}

var arr = [
  { nome: 'abc' },
  { nome: 'abc' },
  { nome: 'abc' }
];

compareArrayValues(arr, 'nome', function(response) {
  console.log(response);  
});
```

O que eu faço é definir uma função que recebe o array, a key a ser comparada, e uma função de retorno `(callback)`, depois faço um `loop` pra comparar os elementos do array e chamo a função de `callback` com a resposta.